# Arduino Orion Upload - Which Board When Compiling

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm trying to compile and upload the example code for the arduino robotics starter kit (https://github.com/Makeblock-official/Makeblock-Library and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Makeblock-official/Assembly-Instructions/master/Starter_Robot_Kit_IR_Instruction.pdf).

In the IDE to compile the code, you need to select the appropiate 'board' for the sketch, and the Arduino Orion isn't listed.  Should I just compile under the Arduino Uno, which I believe the Orion is based on?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the "Orion" is just an Uno in a different shape with different connectors.  Just treat it like an ordinary Uno.

Similarly the "Baseboard" is just a Leonardo in a different shape with different connectors.